# ¿Hay alguna manera de encontrar el máximo entre más de dos valores en dax, fila por fila en una tabla de resumen?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Buenos días: necesito encontrar el valor máximo de todas las columnas que ven en la imagen, fila por fila en DAX, ¿hay alguna manera de hacerlo? El principal problema que tengo es que la función MAX() solo me da 2 parámetros y no más.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probé MAXX(), pero no obtuve buenos resultados ya que esta función no admite booleanos.